# Use regex to replace sequences in a string with modified characters

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am trying to solve a [codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p158175) problem using regular expressions whether it works on the website or not.

So far, I have the following code which does not add a `*` between the two consecutive equal characters. Instead, it just bulldozes over them and replaces them with a set string.

```
public String pairStar(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z])\\1", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if(matcher.find())
    matcher.replaceAll(str);//this is where I don't know what to do
    return str;
}
```

I want to know how I could keep using regex and replace the whole string. If needed, I think a recursive system could help.

Comment: so where is the asterisk (*) in your regex?

Comment: do i need one if it is just finding instances where it is 2 consecutive equal characters?

Comment: goal: turn (char)(samechar) into (char)*(samechar)

Comment: You need to add the '*' when you find the two equal characters.

Comment: FWIW, back-references are expensive.  I just used a StringBuilder and scanned though the input.  Oh, BTW, the codingbat problem didn't say anything about being case-insensitive.

Comment: And why does codingbat think this should be solved recursively?

Comment: My goal is not to solve the codingbat problem :P  This can be done rather quickly.  I want to learn how to put in the '*' in the correct spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
while(str.matches(".*(.)\\1.*")) {
    str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1*$1");
}
return str;
```

#### Explanation of the regex:

The search regex `(.)\\1`:

- `(.)` means "any character" (the `.`) and the brackets create a group - group 1 (the first left bracket)
- `\\1`, which in regex is `\1` (a java literal `String` must escape a backslash with another backslash) means "the first group" - this kind of term is called a "back reference"

So together `(.)\1` means "any repeated character"

The replacement regex `$1*$1`:

- The `$1` term means "the content captured as group 1"

#### Recursive solution:

Technically, the solution called for on that site is a *recursive* solution, so here is recursive implementation:

```
public String pairStar(String str) {
    if (!str.matches(".*(.)\\1.*")) return str;
    return pairStar(str.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "$1*$1"));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just did about half a dozen puzzles from that site. NONE of them required or even benefited from recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know java, but I believe there is replace function for string in java or with regular expression. Your match string would be

```
([a-z])\\1
```

And the replace string would be

```
$1*$1
```

After some searching I think you are looking for this,

```
str.replaceAll("([a-z])\\1", "$1*$1").replaceAll("([a-z])\\1", "$1*$1");
```

Comment: This solution is wrong, though. Given `aaaa`, you are supposed to return `a*a*a*a`

Comment: @nhahtdh `str.replaceAll("([a-z])\\1", "$1*$1").replaceAll("([a-z])\\1", "$1*$1");` should always work. :)

Comment: Right - it passed the test cases on codingbat. Actually, there is way to solve this with single regex (no loop, no recursion, just a single `replaceAll`).

Comment: @nhahtdh it might be possible. But I am against wasting a lot of time to find a regex. It just time wasting when it takes time to find a good regex while you can do it in trivial way in 10 mins.

Comment: It depends though. I used recursion at first - later when I learn advanced regex, I can write it very quickly. This is not a very practical problem - so I think of it as a challenge of whether some form of solution is possible or not.

Comment: Why not you answer containing the single regex solution? I know it can be done with conditional.

Comment: You can have a look at my (newly added) answer.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's a non-recursive solution:

```
public String pairStar(String str) {
  int len = str.length();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len*2);
  char last = '\0';
  for (int i=0; i < len; ++i) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == last) sb.append('*');
    sb.append(c);
    last = c;
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my own solutions.

**Recursive solution** (which is probably more or less the solution that the problem is designed for)

```
public String pairStar(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 1) return str;
    else return str.charAt(0) +
                (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(1) ? "*" : "") +
                pairStar(str.substring(1));
}
```

If you want to complain about `substring`, then you can write a helper function `pairStar(String str, int index)` which does the actual recursion work.

**Regex one-liner one-function-call solution**

```
public String pairStar(String str) {
  return str.replaceAll("(.)(?=\\1)", "$1*");
}
```

Both solution has the same spirit. They both check whether the current character is the same as the next character or not. If they are the same then insert a `*` between the 2 identical characters. Then we move on to check the next character. This is to produce the expected output `a*a*a*a` from input `aaaa`.

The normal regex solution of `"(.)\\1"` has a problem: it consumes 2 characters per match. As a result, we failed to compare whether the character after the 2nd character is the same character. The look-ahead is used to resolve this problem - it will do comparison with the next character without consuming it.

This is similar to the recursive solution, where we compare the next character `str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(1)`, while calling the function recursively on the substring with only the current character removed `pairStar(str.substring(1)`.